# CSS Background on body not respecting width

Tags: css

Having a body with a max width and a "cover" background image width

```
body {
    max-width: 300px;
    background-image: ...;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

the image does not look at the body width, but at the viewport width instead (FF, Chrome and IE). Is there a way around this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tAB2S/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a max-width to the html too. not only the body.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tAB2S/3/)

```
html { max-width: 300px;}

body {
            max-width: 300px;
            background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
        body > div {
            height: 300px;
        }
```

Comment: Wow, you are right. I did not know you can do that. In particular, I was surprised that i still could set the background color for the whole viewport. So in some way, the `background-image` of `body` applies to the whole width of `html`. And the `background-color`/`background-image` of `html` applies to the viewport. Strange, but consistent across browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/tAB2S/4/

Comment: My answer isn't the best way, but now at least you know about the html class. @KhanhTO 's answer is a bit better I think :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        body {
            max-width: 300px;
            background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD/gAIDAAABvUlEQVR42u2b2Y7DIAxFx4j//2XPQ6UoTUYdUDBeevxcNXB8vREiqvqDjVkDAbBMrP/7CxFZ9bDsId9HGK3a5ELuLp6Q4xn3neQSgpEnzhB6mUixWPnFAa1STqEaAgtYwMKABSxgAQtYwMKABSxgAQtYxex+mgisT3Y54AMWYZgXlulLHZQFrPxac1NWRl4+sJK+c2voaHzBDR2NL7tF816CMNy/7oxya9mDZTesMh32JmUhq0Ctw5/OUNVcomY2BBawvh1WrsLSE63V4ra5m7JEZM9N91cZ3V9J+9rNnPdg5PzX36ZX1sX59QbvZrEfuzDxLQhtIaaDlMWuRMS9dPb4Pj/7oGzrcB79Hm41SDtm25SqaqXzjB1N6f10YZxgqGOJTR38hc5Uto6jTZ9xZySdBTzqcpsNP3xBG3bM9h+kE1UAzrOABSxgAQtYGLCABSxgAauE8aHTo4kVWIQhsIAFLGBhwJqEle7WsLOy4EUYLp54gDUx8bx96EQkEobAcodFJE4rC14TsNDXKCy+0pxO8IiLagisjdapho9gkeZHwxBZTfdZcCHBl07w0e/Bh1pftAQqZChyFrC87Rc9QsO8Gm6jLgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="); 
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
        body > div {
            height: 300px;
        }
```

Should not use `background-size: cover;` ,use `background-size: contain;` and `background-repeat:no-repeat;`.

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tAB2S/1/)

Comment: No, sorry. `contain` and `cover` are two considerably different concepts. By accident width and height were 300px in my example, but one or the other could be larger.

Comment: @mh543: I did think that your question is about how to make the image **contained** inside the body. Did I understand your requirement correctly?

Comment: Yes and no. I want the image to be contained (i.e. not to extend outside the box), but to fill the whole box (not `contain` but `cover`). It is strange that `background-size:contain` looks at the element's width for any div, but behaves different for body (change `body` to `div` in the Fiddle's CSS to see the difference).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
body
{
background-position:10px;
width:310px;
}
```

Thanks
AB